Rank high for rich snippets for similar events
I'm trying to figure out the best way to approach this with my website.
I have an event page which talks about the venue then sub pages which represent the dates the event runs to which I should use rel canonical.
Here's an example of the URL structure.
http://example.com/venues/myvenue
is the folder that lists all the events happening inside the venue myvenue.
http://example.com/venues/myvenue/event1
http://example.com/venues/myvenue/event2
http://example.com/venues/myvenue/event3
http://example.com/venues/myvenue/event4
lists the individual events. Only differences between each event is the acceptable age group and date.
I did use a script similar to the LD+JSON examples found at:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/event
If I were to do a rel canonical on each individual event page, how can I still inform google that I have events on multiple days in a rich snippet format?
Do I put 4 LD+JSON events scripts on the category page with URLS in each script pointing to each event page while using rel-canonical on the event page themselves?
or what do I do? because without using rel canonical, one site claims my rank will drop because google won't know what page to rank and that I'm wasting google's crawler budget.
Also, each event is dated about one week apart, but doesn't necessarily run on the exact specific day of the week or a specific time.
